# violate CORS policy when use a localhost bloburl in audio

Tags: html, audio, cors, blob, flask-cors

I generated some mp3 data and put it into a blob URL to cache it.

```
<audio id="memquiz_audio" controls></audio>
```

```
let audio_ele = document.getElementById("memquiz_audio");
let audio_data = new Blob(data, {"type": "audio/mp3"});
audio_src_mementry = window.URL.createObjectURL(audio_data);
audio_ele.src = audio_src_mementry; //throw error
```

The error is

```
refused to load media from 'blob:http://127.0.0.1:9200/14f854fa-3b6c-4d9e-96e7-4c702aaf4f6f' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "media-src 'self' 127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1:9201 127.0.0.1:9200".
```

However, 127.0.0.1 is already in both my cors default-src and media-src.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
default-src: 'self' blob:

rather than:
default-src: 'self' "127.0.0.1" blob:

or
default-src: 'self' 'blob:'